# Performance cost of listening to stream redis in Nestjs with ioredis

Tags: redis, nestjs, ioredis

I have a nestjs application. I also have a redis server fed with simple floats by another of my applications. Operations per second vary between 10 and 100 operations per second.

I'd like my nestjs application to listen to around 800 streams, to redirect messages from the streams to websockets, but I don't know to what extent listening to so many streams has an impact on performance.

Here's a simple exemple of what I want to do.

```
const streams: string[]; // array with approximately 800 stream keys
async subscribeToStreams(streams: string[]): Promise<void> {
    for (const stream of streams) {
        this.redisClient.xread('BLOCK', 0, 'STREAMS', stream, '$', (err, streamData) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error('Error reading stream:', err);
                return;
            }

            // redirect data received to a websocket channel
        });
    }
}
```

With all these features, even though I know it also depends on the server hardware, is it possible to estimate the load approximately? In your experience, are streams heavy to handle?